# No mostrar los espacios y tabs en VS Code

Tags: php, vscode

Alguien sabe como puedo ocultar esto en mi vs Code? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira a des-seleccionar la opción que aparece en Ver > Apariencia > Representar espacio en blanco.

Este es el flag de configuración que controla lo que entiendo que necesitas.